# MVC SignalR TSQL Issue With DateTime

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, model-view-controller, signalr

I'm trying to migrate from ASP.NET WebForms to MVC and have used [this example](http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/)
which worked fine using SQL Server 2008 Express hosted on an Azure VM.  However once I modified the SQL from the "Step 6: Get the  Data from the Repository" section of the tutorial:

```
    public class MessagesRepository
{
    readonly string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    public IEnumerable<Messages> GetAllMessages()
    {
        var messages = new List<Messages>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [MessageID], [Message], [EmptyMessage], [Date] FROM [dbo].[Messages]", connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    messages.Add(item: new Messages { MessageID = (int)reader["MessageID"], Message = (string)reader["Message"], EmptyMessage =  reader["EmptyMessage"] != DBNull.Value ? (string) reader["EmptyMessage"] : "", MessageDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]) });
                }
            }

        }
        return messages;


    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            MessagesHub.SendMessages();
        }
    }
}
```

Which I changed the SQL to this:

```
    @"SELECT [AssignedToUser], [Status], [RequestID] FROM [dbo].[Notifications] WHERE AssignedToUser IS NOT NULL AND Status IS NOT NULL AND RequestID IS NOT NULL AND AssignedToUser = 'Kyle G' AND Status = 'Red'
```

Which worked fine but when I wanted to get only notifications stamped with today's date and appended my SQL:

```
     AND CAST(TimeStatusChange AS DATE) = CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

Or even this:

```
     AND   TimeStatusChange >= (GetDate() - 1)
```

It fails to update unless you refresh the page.  Any ideas friends?
Note-TimeStatusChange is a datetime field.

I converted the current day and database field "TimeStatusChange" as such:

```
    SELECT convert(varchar(25), TimeStatusChange, 120) AS  TimeStatusChange, [Id],[AssignedToUser], [Status], [RequestID] FROM [dbo].[Notifications] WHERE AssignedToUser IS NOT NULL AND Status IS NOT NULL AND RequestID IS NOT NULL AND AssignedToUser = 'Kyle G' AND Status = 'Red' AND convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 112) = convert(varchar(25), TimeStatusChange, 112) ORDER BY TimeStatusChange DESC
```

It should be noted that the issue remains and is not that the SQL when run VS 2015 or SSMS does not work it does.  It also works on a page refresh of the MVC page.  It does not push the new record to the page in real time without a page refresh.

Here is the results in SSMS using Convert for both the TimeStatusChange and getdate() objects:
[image]

In other words if I do this (Essentially an "If 1==1" test):

```
    SELECT TimeStatusChange FROM [dbo].[Notifications] WHERE  convert(varchar(25), TimeStatusChange, 112) = convert(varchar(25), TimeStatusChange, 112)
```

SignalR Updates the page upon INSERT of new record.

If I change it to compare the DB field to today's date as strings:

```
    SELECT TimeStatusChange FROM [dbo].[Notifications] WHERE  convert(varchar(25), TimeStatusChange, 112) = convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 112)
```

SignalR no longer updates the page on INSERT new record unless I refresh it.  The SQL works it just breaks SignalR from updating the page without a refresh.

If I do the opposite If 1==1 test by comparing today's date to itself as a string:

```
    SELECT TimeStatusChange FROM [dbo].[Notifications] WHERE  convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 112) = convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 112)
```

This also breaks SignalR from updating the page UNLESS I refresh the page.  The clue seems to be a problem with:

```
    convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 112)
```

Breaking SignalR, not the SQL.  Perhaps this is too difficult to troubleshoot without having the full solution available.

Comment: Convert returns a string and you are trying to compare it to a date.

Comment: Aha!  Thanks @Dan Bracuk.  Do you have a suggestion as to how to get today's date as just the date and no time as a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it (Thanks to Kamran & Dan for hints).  I do not understand why this worked but by passing the current date into the SQL statement as a string as opposed to using getdate() or DATEADD in SQL made it work! Why is beyond my pay grade.

Here is the working code (yes I will parameterize it!)

```
     string dateof = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Id],[AssignedToUser], [Status], [RequestID] FROM [dbo].[Notifications] WHERE  '" + dateof + "' = convert(varchar(25), TimeStatusChange, 101) ORDER BY TimeStatusChange DESC", connection))
```

Comment: Good to hear. C# is funny like that!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question " Do you have a suggestion as to how to get today's date as just the date and no time as a date?"

Here is how you would convert the dates:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
```

and the results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kamran I had actually done similar but I can't figure out how to post code properly in comments so please see my edited question above.

Comment: @KyleGMotion this might sounds silly but do you want to try SELECT TimeStatusChange FROM [dbo].[Notifications] WHERE  CAST(convert(varchar(25), TimeStatusChange, 112) AS DATE) =  CAST(convert(varchar(25), TimeStatusChange, 112) AS DATE)

Comment: thanks I'll try that now.  I'm at the point where silly ideas are worth it!

Comment: No luck same issue.  The SQL works but SignalR does not update the page on INSERT.  However if you refresh the page it appears.

Comment: That to me suggest something other than the SQL

Comment: If I do this '2016-01-13' = '2016-01-13' it works indicating an issue that does not show in normal SQL execution but that SignalR does not like.  I am suspecting a Jquery issue with the date format.  I'll try other formats.

Comment: Agreed Kamran I'll focus on date format rather than SQL and let you know.  Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries. I'd be interested to know how you go.

Comment: Thanks Kamran I finally got it with your help!